# Finding a particular solution to undetermined coefficients problem that will be part of the fundamental set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, homogeneous-equation

[The problem at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG75g.png)

[My working so far: I am not sure where to go from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68olZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Don't rely on picture to show your work. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).